# @RequestParam and angularjs $http.post data retrieval

Tags: angularjs, arrays, spring, http, angular-http

I am trying to send an array

```
arr=["xxx.yyy","zzz.vvv"]
```

to spring endpoint like this:

```
$http.post("url",arr)
```

spring side:

```
@PostMapping(value = "url")
    public Set<String> func(@RequestParam(name="arr") String[] arr) {

    }
```

however I keep on recieveing

`org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String[] parameter 'arr' is not present`

how can I acces the array by the parameter name? I need to send a few arrays, so I assume they could be referenced by their names, however @RequestParam doesn't seem to work

Comment: We would need to know how your backend is expecting the data and with which `content-type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see from the spring documentation:

> @RequestParam is for URL query parameters
>
> @RequestBody is for parameters from body

As post send the information in the request body, try using the latest one:

```
@PostMapping(value = "url")
public Set<String> func(@RequestBody String[] arr) {

}
```

You may also need to modify the angular part as:

```
$http.post("url",{arr: arr})
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular:

```
getUsuarioId(id:number): Observable<Usuario>{
    return this.http.post<Usuario>(`${this.url}usuarioId`, id, {headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'id': `${id}`}} )
}
```

Java:

```
@PostMapping("/usuarioId")
public Usuario getUserId(@RequestHeader  Integer id) {
    return usuarioService.findByIdUsuario(id);
}
```

You can change the id variable to a json, as follows:

```
getUsuarioId(id:number): Observable<Usuario> {
    let params  = {
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
      'id':`${id}`
    }
    return this.http.post<Usuario>(`${this.url}usuarioId`, params, {headers: params})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Second parameters should be an object, `array` and `secondArray` represent the name of the parameters.  `yourArray` and `anotherArray` will be your array inside the Angular App.

```
$http.post(url', {
           array: yourArray,
           secondArray: anotherArray,
    });
```

Then, on your BE side, you will refer to those value as `array` and `secondArray` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a params object with `arr` as the key:

```
var params = {
    'arr': ["xxx.yyy","zzz.vvv"]
};

$http.post("url", params);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr=["xxx.yyy","zzz.vvv"]
var sendData = {data:arr};

$http.post("url", sendData);
```

In spring you can get sendData. And when you are going to fetch values, you should give the key or index. Ex. arr[0], arr.name

Answer (score 0):

To send multiple arrays trough a post there should be an object on the spring side, e.g. ArrayWrapper that will hold 3 arrays and then an ArrayWrapper object should be sent trough angular, if you're using a library like jackson it will convert the object from requestbody to proper java object you can further process.